# login password verify codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, passwords, codeigniter-4

I can't login even though I enter the correct password.

**controller**

```
    function check()
  {
    // validasi input
    if(!$this->validate([
    //validtion
    ])) {
      return redirect()->to('/auth')->withInput();
    }

    $email = $this->request->getVar('email');
    $password = $this->request->getVar('password');
    $user_info  = $this->userModel->where('email', $email)->first();
    $check_password  = Hash::check($password, $user_info['password']);
```

check password

```
if (!$check_password) {
          session()->setFlashdata('pesan', 'Password yang anda masukkan salah!');
          return redirect()->to('/auth')->withInput();
        } else {
          $user_id = $user_info['id'];
          session()->set('loggedUser', $user_id);
          return redirect()->to('/dashboard');
        }
      }
```

**My libraries hash**

```
<?php 
namespace App\libraries;

class hash
{
  public static function check($password, $db_password)
  {
    if (password_verify($password, $db_password)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
?>
```

can anyone help me how to do this.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check if values of $password and $check_password variables, it is possible that the password you saved in the database is in another format like, md5 and you are comparing it with normal string passed from the form..

Comment: What is the data type of the `password` column in your database

Answer (score -1):

the problem isn't with your code. THE PROBLEM IS MOST LIKELY THE PASSWORD FORMAT IN YOUR DATABASE STRUCTURE. **If you have your password format set to VARCHAR 50 or (which means; a variable character with a maximum length of 50), YOU WOULD NEED TO CHANGE THE LENGHT TO 80 OR 100 TO BE SAFE.**

The reason for the above is that the Hash function in Code Igniter-4 tends to encrypt/convert characters into lengths greater than 50. So if the password format length is set to 50, the Database is forced to truncate/shorten the encrypted characters when they're getting saved into the Database which then creates a problem when you're trying to decrypt the password when using the **Check** or **Password_Verify functions**, because the complete length characters are no longer available for decryption.